# php row id doesnt display inside adressbar after clicking on link

Tags: php, html

So i am trying to display the id inside the adressbar. On previous pages it already works but in this one it doesn't seem to work and i dont know why. The arrows shows where the problem lies

My disired result is that this adress bar https://nottherealsiteurl/upload.php?id=

to turn into this   https://nottherealsiteurl/upload.php?id= $row['id'](id from database)

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT chauffeurs_naam, ritten.id ,chauffeurs.cc, ritten_date, ritten_totaal, ritten_naam, ritten_start, ritten_end, ritten_pauze, Kenteken, km_end, Onderhoudsrit
FROM ritten
JOIN chauffeurs
ON ritten.rit_cc = chauffeurs.cc
JOIN users
ON users.cc = chauffeurs.cc
WHERE users.id =".$_GET['id']. "";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
?>



<form action="upload.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'];?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<h3>Select image to upload:</h3>
    <input class="button button2" type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" required="required">
    <input class="button button2" type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

On other pages where its does get displayed.

its put like this.
 Again i put the arrows where it does work

```
$sql = "SELECT chauffeurs_naam, c.id, c.cc, c.chauffeurs_foto FROM chauffeurs c JOIN users u ON c.cc=u.cc WHERE u.id =".$_GET['id']."";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo"<div class='col-xl-3 col-md-6 card'>";
        if (isset($row['chauffeurs_foto'])) {
          echo "<div class='caption'><img class='avatar-cards' alt='Generic placeholder thumbnail' src=''/></div>";
        }
        else {
          echo "<img class='avatar-cards' alt='Generic placeholder thumbnail' src='images/Test_Foto_Chauffeur.png'/>";
        }
        echo "<a href='Update_image.php?id=". $row['id'] ."'>Aanpassen</a>";
        echo "<div class='card-body'>";
        echo "<h4>". $row['chauffeurs_naam'] ."</h4>";
        echo"<p class='card-text'>";
        echo "Chauffeurs-nummer: ". -------------------->$row['id']<--------------------------- ."<br/>";
        echo "</p>";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "</div>";
        }
```

Comment: You should rather try and avoid such a mix of GET and POST parameters. Put the ID into the value of a hidden field in your form, then it will submit together with the other parameters as a POST parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on this line upload.php?id= you missing echo and semi colon

```
upload.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'];?>
```

try this hope it work.

and i have run your code and cross checked its working now , once just check with simple query and if worked cross check your query that its getting data or not

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * from tab_1";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
?>



<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styling.css">
<title>Image Upload Tutorial</title>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<h1>Php Photo Upload Tutorial</h1>
<form action="upload.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'];?>" method="post" 
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<h3>Select image to upload:</h3>
<input class="button button2" type="file" name="fileToUpload" 
id="fileToUpload" required="required">
<input class="button button2" type="submit" value="Upload Image" 
name="submit">
</form>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

above complete code working fine

Comment: Haha if thats the solution im going to be so embarrassed thanks anyway

Comment: wait a second , if you run sql query does you executed it and fetched data on query that at starting?